# Using inline to Insert a header content

Tags: c++, c, include, c++-cli, c-preprocessor

The content of a header file needs to be copied and paste onto a few of my classes. Reason been - using include directive does not make reference of the file available to an external compiler, therefore it looks like my only option been to copy the content of the header into my classes.

I was wondering if I can use specific ***inline** directives to achieve this.

What are the best approach to creating my own pre-processor to behave as such?!

Comment: What external compiler are you talking about?

Comment: @John Zwinck It is an ODB compiler

Comment: This C++ ORM thing?  http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/odb/doc/odb.xhtml ... what doesn't work if you use its `-I` option to tell it where to find your include files?

Comment: @Bitmap: Why don't you use another compiler to perform only preprocessing and feed the generated files to the ODB compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause of your *external* compiler not expanding the includefile when compiling  is a failure to setup the include search path -- however addressing the specific question, you can get the gcc compiler to expand all the include files using the `-E` option.

So,

```
  gcc -E mycfile.c >myexpeandedcfile.c
```

should work assuming I understand you problem correctly.

Comment: I have to confirm this has nothing to do with ODB as it does expand the include file. In general your answer is what I expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

How about using the m4 macro language?  See, e.g.,

- http://www.gnu.org/s/m4/
- http://mbreen.com/m4.html
- If on a Linux system with GNU m4 installed, try `info m4`.

m4 is a general-purpose macro processing language.  It is notably used heavily in GNU Autotools.  You might be able to define some m4 macros to get what you want and then pre-process your code by running it through m4 before compilation, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create your own pre-processor tool to do the equivalent of `#include`.

Comment: If the real task is to fully resolve all #includes, not just selected ones, the actual C preprocessor could be used.  I suspect it may be like you say, though.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what compiler you are using to compile your binaries.  Some compilers offer optimization flags that can affect the inlining of your program.  In gcc and g++, the optimization flag -finline-functions will force the inlining of functions it deems "simple".  The compiler uses a set of heuristics to determine a function's simplicity, so this may or may not work, depending on your code.  The -finline-function flag is also set by optimization level 3, enabled in gcc and g++ with the flag -O3.

With a little tweaking and adding inline directives to your code, you should be able to set some compiler flags to achieve full inlining.